# Where are these ancient texts online in Unicode format?

Tags: comparative

I am looking for some potentially lesser well-known texts from these languages:

- Korea
- Georgia
- Kannada
- Bengali
- Persian (Avesta)
- Gujarati
- Amharic
- Urdu
- Cyrillic
- etc.
- Agama (Sufi)
- Tantra
- Thai
- Telugu
- Armenian
- Coptic
- Turkish

Are there any of these ancient texts *in Text format* (i.e. not PDF or scanned book).

Looking for it in the original language, not an English translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange question. That is far more language than a modern man or anyone ever talked!
I can't give texts to all of that, but:

- Coptic: You have the fairly excellent [Coptic scriptorium](https://copticscriptorium.org/), you probably don't need any other resource that this one, both huge and complete. You will need a little bit of copy paste, considering you have the text in coptic, a transliteration and a traduction. You can find easily resources among the Egyptolists around you.
- The [sahidica manuscript full version](https://www.stepbible.org/version.jsp?version=CopSahidicMSS) from STEP

- Old Persian, You have:
 -     the [old Persian Corpus](http://titus.uni-frankfurt.de/texte/etcs/iran/airan/apers/apers.htm) This one is written in cuneiform
 -     the [avesta](http://www.avesta.org/op/op.htm) this one is old Persian in modern alphabet
 -     the [Texas liberal art](https://lrc.la.utexas.edu/eieol_toc/aveol) same as above, modern alphabet render of ancient cuneiform script, so no cuneiform just the transliteration, include a full grammar
 -     the [Achaemenid royal inscription](http://oracc.museum.upenn.edu/ario/), again, alphabet render of cuneiform
 - Middle Persian used several scripting system, Aramic and Avestan,
 - Here is the [Vendidad](http://www.avesta.org/vendidad/vd_tc.htm) in Avestan, think to download the [Avestan font](http://www.avesta.org/fonts/index.html) and switch to Avestan to see the text properly.

A little note on Persian Cuneiform: It is easy to find Persian cuneiform in cuneiform corpus... you just need to understand what you are reading, which is semi problematic (historically the cuneiform was deciphered using precisely a Persian inscription, the one at Behitsun). reading cuneiform is hard (way harder than hieroglyph, by magnitude), due to its inconstancy geographically and over time, while the language cuneiform is expressing is quite stable (learn standard Babylonian and you read fluently old Babylonian and Assyrian), so it is very usual to just find transliterations (not to mention cuneiform in written on clay which is almost impossible to read on photos, so you need either a drawing or a prepared text). So it is the original language, not the original scripting system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Coptic Scriptorium is no good, it only has maybe 100 short (1 page) documents, I am looking for something with MEAT on the bones. Something like a novel or bible or something (I've seen the Coptic bible), but in Coptic. Maybe 1000 pages of songs or something, I don't know. I saw that Avesta but it's not in Farsi, I want the original script! :)